# How to populate a ListBox with values from a custom class with WinForms in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

On my WinForms project I have a ListBox control as well as multiple labels. I also have a custom `Person` class where the values get assigned from a text file CSV. This `Person` class has properties such as `Name, Gender, Weight,` etc.

What I would like to happen is for all of the `Name` properties in the `Person` class to be added to the ListBox control. And following this, when the user selects this `Person` by clicking on him/her in the ListBox, the labels get updated with that persons corresponding values. I hope this makes sense. I have included an image of the form to help you get a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I have tried the following code, however the ListBox isn't being updated with any values.

```
public void Get_Roster()
{
    string line;
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Austin316\Desktop\yourFile.txt");

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] words = line.Split(',');

        Person p = new Person(words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5], words[6], words[7], words[8], words[9], words[10], words[11]);

        foreach (Person b in people)
        {
            lstRoster.Items.Add(p.Name).ToString();
        }
    }

    file.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have issue in your code to populating listbpx control
see this code may help you:

```
public void Get_Roster()
{
    string line;
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Austin316\Desktop\yourFile.txt");

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] words = line.Split(',');

        Person p = new Person(words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5], words[6], words[7], words[8], words[9], words[10], words[11]);

        // Add the person to the list
        people.Add(p);
        // Add the person's name to the ListBox
        lstRoster.Items.Add(p.Name);
    }

    file.Close();
}
```

Now, each time you read a line from the file and create a Person object, you add that person to both the people list and the ListBox. This should correctly populate the ListBox with the names of the people from your file.

To handle the selection event and update the labels, you can use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the ListBox:

```
private void lstRoster_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the selected person from the people list
    Person selectedPerson = people[lstRoster.SelectedIndex];

    // Update labels with the selected person's information
    lblName.Text = selectedPerson.Name;
    lblGender.Text = selectedPerson.Gender;
    // Add more label updates for other properties as needed
}

public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lstRoster.SelectedIndexChanged += lstRoster_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

Replace YourForm with the actual name of your form class.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. First issue solved perfectly. As for the second, I get an error message of 'the name 'people' does not exist in the current context.' How can I solve this? I am obviously very new to C# haha.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding each item in a loop, create a list and add each person to the list followed by setting the list to the DataSource property of the ListBox.

To get the Name property to show, added .ToString as shown below which becomes the DisplayMember of the ListBox.

```cs
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Mocked loading data and data binding the name property to a label. Continue adding other labels as needed.

```cs
List<Person> list = new List<Person>
{
    new Person() { Name = "Anne", Gender = "Female", Weight = 99},
    new Person() { Name = "Jon", Gender = "Male", Weight = 150}
};

lstRoster.DataSource = list;
NameLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", list, "Name");
```

And if you need to get at say the selected item use the following

```cs
if (lstRoster.SelectedItem is not null)
{
    var person = (Person) lstRoster.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show($"{person.Name}, {person.Gender}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately for the 'var person = (Person) lstRoster.SelectedItem; I get a System.InvalidCastException error: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Test.Peson'. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much, truly appreciate you! :-)